# Are ordinal models technically a GLM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, multinomial-distribution, multinomial-logit

I'm following [Agresti's book](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Foundations+of+Linear+and+Generalized+Linear+Models-p-9781118730034). Specifically, chapter 6 which deals with multinomial models. In that he shows how a nominal response can be modeled by a baseline category GLM, and shows it can be viewed as a vector/multi-variate GLM (6.1.1 and 6.1.2), by putting it EDM (exponential dispersion family) form.

He then moves to talk about ordinal models, and states that they model the cumulative probabilities, e.g. by
$$\text{logit} P(y_i \le j) = \alpha_j + x_i\beta$$

That's great, but technically GLM's uses the EDF form, and the link functions link the mean of the distributions to the linear predictor. Not some cumulative distribution quantity. The EDM form is not shown for the ordinal models. So, are ordinal models actually a GLM, or are they a likelihood maximum model that get bundled together with other GLMs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ordinal model that you state is called the proportional odds ordinal logistic regression model (POLR), and was popularized by Peter McCullagh (McCullagh 1980).
Yes, it is a generalized linear model (GLM), but it is a multivariate rather than a univariate GLM.

The EDM in this case is the multivariate multinomial distribution.
The vector of cumulative probabilities $P(y_i \le j)$ for the ordinal response can be written as a linear transformation of the mean of the multinomial distribution, and hence the proportional odds logistic model can be written as a multivariate link-linear equation in terms of the multinomial mean.

The full GLM framework for the POLR model was written out explicitly in my 1991 paper on EDMs.
I've never seen it written out explicitly anywhere else.
It is a multivariate GLM for which the mean parameter is a vector and the variance function produces matrix values, equal to the multinomial covariance matrix.

**References**

McCullagh, P. (1980). Regression models for ordinal data. *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Methodological)*, 42, 109-127.

Smyth, G.K. (1991). Exponential dispersion models and the Gauss-Newton algorithm. *Australian Journal of Statistics* 33, 57–64.
https://gksmyth.github.io/pubs/edm-gna.pdf